# How to speed up parallel foreach in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I want to calculate a series of approx 1.000.000 wilcox.tests in R:

```
result <- foreach(i = 1:ncol(data), .combine=bind_rows, .multicombine= TRUE, .maxcombine = 1000  ) %do% { 

w = wilcox.test(data[,i]~as.factor(groups),exact = FALSE)

df <- data.frame(Characters=character(),
                   Doubles=double(),
                   Doubles=double(),
                   stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

  df[1,] = c(colnames(data)[i], w$statistic, w$p.value)

  rownames(df) = colnames(beta_t1)[i]
  colnames(df) = c("cg", "statistic", "p.value")

  return(df)

}
```

If I do it with %dopar% and 15 cores it is slower than with single core %do%.
I suspect it is a memory access problem. My processors are hardly used to capacity either. Is it possible to split the data dataframe into chunks and then have each processor calculate 100K and then add them together? How can I speed up this foreach loop?

Comment: If you suspect that it's a memory access problem, check out the package iterators, it works well together with foreach: https://cran.r-project.org/package=iterators

Comment: If you don't need the Wilcoxon test statistic you can significantly speed up the calculation of those parallel wilcox.tests (in the range of two orders of magnitude) with `pairwiseWilcox` from the `scran` package, even without parallelization, but it can use `BiocParallel` as well. Assuming `data` being a numeric matrix with 1E6 columns and n rows, and group a factor with 2 levels and length n, `scran::pairwiseWilcox(t(data), groups)` would give you p-values and effect sizes.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that’s immediately striking is that you use eight lines to create and return a data.frame where a single expression is sufficient:

```
data.frame(
    cg = colnames(data)[i],
    statistic = w$statistic,
    p.value = w$p.value
    row.names = colnames(beta_t1)[i]
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

However, the upshot is that *after* the loop is run, `foreach` has to row-bind all these data.frames, and that operation is *slow*. It’s more efficient to return a list of the p-values and statistics and forget about the row and column names (these can be provided afterwards, and then don’t require subsetting and re-concatenation).

That is, change your code to

```
result = foreach(col = data) %do% {
    w = wilcox.test(col ~ as.factor(groups), exact = FALSE)
    list(w$statistic, w$p.value)
}

# Combine result and transform it into a data.frame:
results = data.frame(
    cg = colnames(data),
    statistic = vapply(results, `[[`, double(1L), 1L),
    p.value = vapply(results, `[[`, double(1L), 2L),
    row.names = colnames(beta_t1),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE # only necessary for R < 4.0!
)
```

(I never use `foreach` so I’m not exactly sure how to use it here but the above should roughly work; otherwise try `mclapply` from the ‘parallel’ package, it does the same, just using the familiar syntax of `lapply`.)